# PyCharm not displaying Matplotlib plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, pycharm

My program works fine when I view it in scientific mode, but I found that I cannot edit the plot in scientific mode, while I remember I can do that when the plot is displayed in a separate window. So I just disable the `Python Scientific -> Show plots in tool window`, then my program still runs with no error, but no figure is displayed.
Because it can be displayed normally for the scientific mode, I don't think this is the problem of my program. It must be some setting for my PyCharm that went wrong. I have looked for the answers but most of those answers only address the problem of incorrect backend, apparently not applicable to my scenario.

I actually think PyCharm scientific view is more of a hindrance than a help. It reduces the original functionality for editing the plot and only leaves it with a rastered version of the plots.

[image]

In Scientific view it totally reduces the option to adjust the plot, while when I tried to disable the scientific view, nothing was displayed. This is quite annoying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try alternative matplotlib backends eg

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
matplotlib.use('TkAgg') or
matplotlib.use('Qt5Agg')
```

Then turn interactive mode on in IDE by:
plt.ion()  # required for non notebook code from matplotlib .ioff() to turn off

then it should open the window with the plot rendered, PyCharm then pushes it to the background:

```
plt.plot([1, 2, 3, 4])
plt.ylabel('some numbers')
plt.show()
```

Worked for me

PyCharm:
PyCharm 2021.1.1 (Community Edition)
Build #PC-211.7142.13, built on April 21, 2021
Runtime version: 11.0.10+9-b1341.41 amd64
VM: Dynamic Code Evolution 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
Windows 10 10.0
GC: ParNew, ConcurrentMarkSweep
Memory: 1972M
Cores: 12
Registry: debugger.watches.in.variables=false
Non-Bundled Plugins: String Manipulation (8.15.203.000.3), com.jetbrains.plugins.ini4idea (211.6693.44), izhangzhihao.rainbow.brackets (6.17), com.leinardi.pycharm.pylint (0.12.2), com.kite.intellij (1.9.3)

Python 3.8.10

Anaconda Nov 2020 - build x64 windows

Comment: If you don't want to have to add this line to every script that you use, you can find your matplotlibrc config file, which can be found with 
`import matplotlib

print(matplotlib.matplotlib_fname())`
 create a copy of it in User/<you>/.matplotlib/ , open it to edit it, and go to the part where it says "#bakend: " and change it to "backend: TkAgg"

Comment: And then if that doesn't work go into Settings > Tools > Python Scientific > and disable "Show plots in tool window"

Answer (score 3):

try adding the line

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Add this after you have done your plot
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks! But I am familiar with Matplotlib, this is not about the program. It's actually some issue of PyCharm IDE.

Comment: What backend are you using for matplotlib?

Comment: I basically tried all possible backends, but none of them works.

Comment: It reports no error, just doesn't display the fig if I unclick `Show plots in tool window`

Comment: Are you using anaconda? https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-29684

Answer (score 1):

For me, pressing double shift, selecting python scientific and deselecting "`Show plots in tool window`" worked.

Answer (score 0):

If you are receiving no error and you can not see your plot, check the items below:

1. you have `plt.show()` at the very end.
2. On the top right side of the pycharm IDE click on **SciView** and then click on **plots**. Sometimes your plot doesn't appear on the screen but is kept there.

Good Luck